# How do you get FakeVim in the Ubuntu SDK to use ~/.vim/plugin/colemak.vim?

Tags: vim, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, colemak

I have a custom layout for vim, that remaps the keys to fit my colemak keyboard layout.

In the ubuntu SDK, fakevim does not use the custom layout defined in ~/.vim/colemak.vim.

How can get fakevim to use the layout defined in colemak.vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fakevim will not detect plugins that you define for vim, rather you have to place the configuration directly into .vimrc